# getting 403 on nginx deployment (mac)

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I am trying to deploy a react app onto nginx. Here is my server object in the nginx.confg.
Keep getting 403, any help

```
server {
listen       8080;
server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /Users/pinky/Documents/workspace/nebula_fe;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using proxy pass command resolved this issue..